# php/myAdmin version 4.8 - Edit Routines not showing mysql error message

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, phpmyadmin

I updated a few days ago phpMyAdmin till version 4.8

When editing Stored Procedures (SP) the "Edit routine"-modal is not showing detailed mysql error message.

Just to see the difference in editing a SP within the edit routine and with editing in de sql console I added two images:

1. Edit SP in "Edit routine modal" without error detail:

[image: 1. Edit Routine modal without error detail]

2. Edit SP in "SQL console" with error detail:

[image: Edit SP in "SQL console" with error detail]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved in a new version: 4.8.0.1